# Erro conexão PHP 7 (Debian) com Sybase 16

Tags: pdo, conexão, linux, php-7, sybase

Estou com a seguinte dificuldade: Preciso configurar o ambiente PHP para se conectar à uma base SyBase 16. Não sou programador PHP e estou auxiliando um outro colega. Tudo o que foi tentado até agora não funciona.

O codigo é:

```
$connection= new PDO ("dblib:version=4.2;charset=UTF-8;host=".$host.":".$port.";dbname=".$dbname, $username, $password);
```

e obtemos o erro:

```
SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)
```

Existe algum tutorial para isso? Tudo o que eu encontro ou é para o o PHP 5 ou é para Windows.

Mais algumas informaçoes:

```
PHP Version 7.0.26-1~dotdeb+8.2
System Linux websrv01 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64
Server API Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php/7.0/apache2
Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

ATUALIZAÇÃO:

Seguindo as sugestõoes, alteramos o código desta forma:

```
$connection = new PDO("dblib:version=8;charset=UTF-8;host=".$host.":".$port.";dbname=".$dbname, $username, $password);
```

O que resultou em :

```
« SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0) »
```

Outra tentativa foi usar:

```
$connection = new PDO("sybase:host=".$host.":".$port.";dbname=".$dbname, $username, $password);
```

que continua com o erro:

```
« could not find driver »
```

Os drivers foram instalados, mas eu sei que o PHP exige uma configuração no seu INI que eu nao estou sabendo fazer.

Comment: Já tentou modificando a versão do driver? Tente com uma mais recente: `dblib:version=8.0`

Comment: Você afirma no titulo que é php7.2, mas nas informações esta 7.0.26, algo de errado não esta certo.

Comment: Tentou: `sybase:host=".$host.":".$port.";dbname=".$dbname`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Voce tem razao. Foi meu colega que me disse que era 7.2. Realmente é 7. Vou sugerir que ele faça as modificaçoes recomendadas aqui e volto para postar o resultado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP O uso da connectionstring sybase:host=".$host.":".$port.";dbname=".$dbname resultou em “could not find driver”. Apersar do driver sybase estar instalado (https://packages.debian.org/fr/sid/php7.0-sybase) pode ser que ele nao esteja configurado corretamente. Seria esse o problema?